# Remove filters from spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

At start I can see that spring security, by default, includes several filters:

> o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     | Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10092eb, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@603a72f0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2b5c74b4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1a6a9725, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@12611d34, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@a8ce48e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6cf8ab1f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6c0d63e2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@79d02427]

I need none of them as I only need to register a filter that handles authentication via custom means (I will see the contents of some http headers and perform logic on them).
So, is it possible to remove them to leave only my filter?

While we are at it would it also possible to exclude some dependencies to make my jar lighter?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?